# How to use NoSQL REST API of Gamesparks in my Unity project?

Tags: unity, c#, http

Gamesparks has a documentation of the API but I am not sure how to send https requests to use that API.

Comment: Could not find a documentation for REST use in Unity actually. I did not use any REST API in another platform either.

Comment: What are you trying to actually *accomplish*?

Comment: I was trying to use MongoDB from my app. I have chosen to use cloud code of gamesparks. I won't use REST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm part of the customer success team at gamesparks.com
Rest is generally reserved for server to server communication and it would be considered bad practice to use it in your unity client as it adds additional and unnecessary steps.

My advice would be an event that constructs the NoSQL query from data passed as attributes into the event. The query can be constructed from this data. 
Best Regards, Patrick.

Comment: Thank you. That was what I considered first but I could not managed to find how to baseline, or version control of the cloud code. Is there any way that I can tag a cloud code version for a compatible app version?